# Array turns to string after passing as an EJS variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

So I have a file with an array which I am passing to the `ejs template`. I must use that array in a `for loop` to render each item of the array. But all I'm getting right now are the letters in the console. Seems like I somehow turned it into a string.

Can someone help me render each item in the array by using a for loop and also by using proper EJS syntax?

Here's the code:

Example.js

```
router.get('/example', (req, res) => {
    const array         = ['superman', 'batman', 'wonderwoman'];
    res.render("../views/example", { data: array });
});
```

EJS template

```
<script>

    <% if(data) { %>
        const dataArr = '<%- data %>';
        
        for ( let i = 0; i < dataArr.length; i++ ) {             
            console.log(dataArr[i]);
        }
        
    <% }else{ %>
        console.log('no data')
    <% } %>

</script>
```

Comment: Remove the quotes around `'<%- data %>'` in your template

Comment: @blex Hi. Tried without it before but it shows this error in the console - ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration```.

Comment: Oh ok, then you might need to also stringify your data before passing it to your template, in Example.js:  `{ data: JSON.stringify(array) }`

Comment: @blex post this as an answer

Comment: No, it's cool, you can pick _eol_'s answer

Comment: @blex thanks mate for the help.

Comment: Merci @blex! I saw your comment too late, would have let you answer the question instead :)

Comment: Wow. Such beautiful people. Hats off to both of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had a similar problem recently using ejs, what fixed it for me was using the following assignment within the script:

```
const dataArr =  <%-JSON.stringify(data)%>;
```